# How to find the runtime name in mobile first version 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use the management-apis in MobileFirst 8. How do I find the runtime value?. The app is deployed and I can see it in the MobileFirst operation console.

This is the URL from the doc.

https://www.example.com/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/**myruntime**/notifications/applications/myapplication/messages?locale=de_DE

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the runtime name is "mfp".
You can see the runtime definition in the server.xml file of your application server.

In the MobileFirst Foundation Developer Kit, you can find it in **{server-installation}\mfp-server\usr\servers\mfp\server.xml**. Search for the `application` element.

Answer (score 0):

Also, below REST API call will list the runtime names (default is mfp) :

```
http://{host}:{port}/{context}/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/
```

eg: http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes